# Excel RegEx Extraction

Tags: regex, excel, substring, extract, vba

recently I've been trying to extract some strings from text in excel. I used script from other post here: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Since Macro code is working fine I couldn't use in Cell function, it's showing #NAME? error. I've included "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" but still no luck.

I can use it with macro but script needs some changes. I would like to have some strings in A1:A50, then to B1:B50 extract date in format DD Month YYYY (e.g. 28 July 2014) and to C1:C50 extract account no in format G1234567Y.

For now script is replacing date with "". Regular Expression for date is correct but how to insert date into B column? And then A/c no to C column working on 1:50 range? 
This is the code:

```
Sub simpleRegex()
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[0-9][0-9].*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim Out As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set Out = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            Out = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            MsgBox ("Not matched")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank You kindly for any assistance.

Comment: Could you provide an exact example of data in column A?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your replacing the matching string with an empty string "" so that's why your getting no result.  You need to return the actual match using `()` to indicate match set and `$1` to retrieve it.

---

Based on your example, I'll assume your text in column A looks like this: `28 July 2014 G1234567Y`

Here is a routine that will split apart the text into a date and then the text following the date.

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A50")

    For Each C In Myrange
        strPattern = "([0-9]{1,2}.*[0-9]{4}) (.*)"
        'strPattern = "(\d{1,2}.*\d{4}) (.*)"

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = C.Value
            strReplace = "$1"

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
                C.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
                C.Offset(0, 2) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
            Else
                C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

---

To use an in-cell function, set it up to extract a single piece such as Date or everything else.  The following code will extract the date.  Cell `B1` would have the following equation: `=extractDate(A1)`

```
Function extractDate(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strRaplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "(\d{1,2}.*\d{4}) (.*)"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            extractDate = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
        Else
            extractDate = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

To make another function for extracting the rest of the date simply change `$1` to `$2` and it will return the second defined match in the pattern.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help, I think it's time to get some good VbScripting basics.:)